# How to destroy vm runInNewContext

Tags: javascript, node.js, virtual-machine, sandbox

I'm building a tiny script engine in Node.js

My users can start and stop scripts from a web editor. Since the scripts might be unsafe they are run with the VM module using the runInNewContext-function.

Scripts contains a handler with a onMessage-callback and everything works just fine. Handlers are being triggered but I can't find any way of destroying the scripts. The scripts live forever. I start the scripts like this:

```
var sandbox = {
  "setTimeout": setTimeout,
  "setInterval": setInterval,
  "handler": handler,
};

var vmScript = vm.createScript(script.content);
vmScript.runInNewContext(sandbox);
```

I cant fint any way to kill the script.

I've tried to delete the vmScript object with

```
delete vmScript;
```

But that doesn't work. Has anyone managed to stop a script like this?

Comment: Since it's `sandbox` that hold the data and functions shouldn't you delete that?